Delegate missing instance methods to mongoose document
I'm building a Node.js application using MongoDB and Mongoose. I have a 'companies' collection with the following schema:
// app/schemas/company.js
const AboutScheme = new Schema({
    slogan: String,
    description: String,
});

const CompanySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    about: AboutScheme,
    status: String,
    user: ObjectId,
    email: String
});

I'm creating a POJO class to represent a company document. I want this class to handle its own methods and delegate other methods to the underlying Mongoose document.
// app/domains/company.js

class Company {
    constructor(document) {
        this.#document = document;
    }
    
    sendEmail() {
        console.log('sending email...');
    }
    
    toJSON() {
        return this.#document.toObject();
    }
}

The idea is to separate data logic from business logic. But do it transparently for the user:
const CompanyModel = mongoose.model('Company');
const companyDocument = CompanyModel.findOne({ email: 'some@company.com' });
const company = new Company(companyDocument);
company.sendEmail(); // handled by Company class

company.name = 'New Name'; // delegated to this.#document
company.about.slogan = 'new slogan'; // deegated to this.#document

company.save(); // delegated to this.#document


I'm trying to use a Proxy to achieve this transparent delegation, but I'm facing some issues. This doesn't give me access to this.#document and doesn't have the effect of modifying properties within the document when saving (this.#document.about.slogan) among other issues.
class Company {
  #document;
    
  constructor(document) {
    this.#document = document;
        
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get(target, name, receiver) {
        if (self[name]) {
          return self[name];
        }

        return Reflect.get(target, name, receiver);
      },
      set(target, name, value, receiver) {
        return Reflect.set(target, name, value, receiver);
      }
    });
  }
}

Can you help me implement a solution that effectively separates data logic from business logic?

If returning a proxy, the target should be the document, not the Company class the constructor was called against (i.e. this).
The handler get method should contain the methods to be added.  There is no need to create a set method if there will be no additional properties added.
An example of adding a sendEmail method with a discreet handler, and a toJSON that proxies to the contained object's toObject:
class Company {
   constructor(document) {
     return new Proxy(document, { 
        get(target, name, receiver) {
           switch (name) {
              case "sendEmail":
                    return () => console.log("sending email...");
                    break;
              case "toJSON": 
                    return Reflect.get(target, "toObject", receiver); 
                    break;
              default:
                    return Reflect.get(target, name, receiver)
           }
        }
     })
   }
}

let obj = {test: doc => console.log("test " + doc), x:1};

let company = new Company(obj);

console.log(company.x);
company.test("me");
company.sendEmail();

company.x = 5;

console.log(company.x);
console.log(obj.x);

The output from the above is:
1
test me
sending email...
5
5

It is not strictly necessary to create the proxy inside of a class, the same could be achieved with a simple function with the same content as the constructor.
